# How to keep my path from moving when scaling using the "select and transform" tool

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to draw some block diagrams in inkscape using predefined paths that I adjust in length/height, but my paths are moving as soon as I adjust them using the "select and transform"-tool (F1).

Here is an example:

[I snap my path to the correct position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq2l5.png)

[I then adjust its size by dragging the bottem-left corner of the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY9Up.png)

[My path has changed its position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sZeb.png)

I'm not sure why exactly this is happening, so I'd like to know how to keep it in place when changing its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, enable **Geometric bounding box** in *Preferences -> Tools -> Bounding box to use*.

This ensures that the bounding box of a selection ends at the nodes and not at the visual limits of the selection (which includes half trace width, arrows, etc.). This way, when you scale your selection dragging from one side, nodes on the other side of the bounding box stay where they are.

Check [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html) for documentation on transformations.

You should also uncheck the tool control icons for scaling line width and rounded corners (also explained in the link above), so that when you scale a selection, line widths remain fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I seem to have to switch between both Visual and Geometric Bounding Box in the case I want to use the Align and Distribute Tool to align arrowheads, but that's fine.